# Gridster.js auto-arrangement after drag-and-drop

Tags: jquery, resize, dashboard, gridster

Im using Gridster.js for my dashboard, that enables drag and drop and also resizing the widgets. Is there any possibility to auto-arrange the widgets to fit minimal space after moving or resizing one of them?

Comment: I know you wanted a gridster solution. However, I stumbled upon this one: http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html. Maybe, you could give this one a try and let us know.